# Does initializing a variable in the init function of a package ensures a single instance in a golang app?

Tags: go

I am writing a Bloom Filter package.
Within my package, I want to create an instance of `X` (non-exported) which I want to exist only as a single instance; no matter how many times my package is imported into an app.

A simple snippet of what I am doing is:

```
package superduperbloomfilter

var x X

func init() {
    x = X.New(....)
}
```

Is this correct ?

Comment: IT would be better if the Init function checks if it has already been called and only execute the x = X if it the first time.

Comment: Btw for other scenarios there is also http://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Once, just to let you know. But init() works as you expect and your code will work.

Comment: @tchap Wow `Once` is a useful addition to my toolbox. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> which I want to exist only as a single instance; no matter how many
>   times my package is imported into an app

[The spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec#) says an imported package is initialized only once:

> If a package has imports, the imported packages are initialized before
>   initializing the package itself. **If multiple packages import a package
>   P, P will be initialized only once**.